# Issues with Google search results

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

When I go to Google and search for Intranet Dashboard Help it shows me these results.[image: Google Search Results]

**Expected result:** 
- I want to see actual page description in the Search results

**Actual result:** 
- I only see ‘Loading...’ text in the search results

**Can any one please guide me how Google generates this search results and how can I have a control over this list?**

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: adding image for meta tags i have in that page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add `<meta name='description' content=''This is the description of my website'/>` to the head.

Comment: What if... Its loading?
Have you tried to let google crawl your page again?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the first thing the search engine sees is a page with that in the head? if you redirect it first it could break it.

Comment: Yeah I think so. That's the head content on loading the web page.